# $\sup_n \int |f_n|^{1 + \gamma}d\mu < \infty$ implies $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly integrable?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Suppose $\mu$ is a finite measure and for some $\gamma > 0$, we have$$\sup_n \int |f_n|^{1 + \gamma}d\mu < \infty.$$Does it follow that $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly integrable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if $\mu$ is a finite measure and the family $\{f_n\}$ is bounded in $L^p$ for some $p>1$ then it is uniformly integrable.

To prove this, let $M=\sup_{n}||f_n||_p$ and let $q$ be the conjugate exponent of $p$ (note that $q<\infty$). Given $\varepsilon>0$, let $\delta=\frac{\epsilon^q}{M^q}$, and suppose that $\mu(E)<\delta$. Then by Holder's inequality,
$$ \int_E|f_n|\;d\mu\leq ||f_n||_p||1_E||_q\leq M\mu(E)^{\frac{1}{q}}<\varepsilon $$
for all $n$, hence
$$ \sup_n\int_E|f_n|\;d\mu<\varepsilon $$

Comment: Where do you use the fact that $\mu$ is finite here?

Comment: @TheProofIsTrivium Usually the definition of a uniformly integrable set requires all the functions to be in $L^1$, and if $\mu$ is not a finite measure then $L^p$ with $p>1$ is not contained in $L^1$ in general.