# Uniform Integrability of $M^2$ if $M$ is a martingale.

Tags: uniform-convergence, martingales, uniform-integrability

Let $M:\Omega\times\mathbb{R^+}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a martingale such that
\begin{equation*}
\sup_{t\in \mathbb{R}^+}\mathbb{E}[M_t^2]<\infty
\end{equation*}
Then is $M$ uniformly integrable? i.e. is it true that
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{K\rightarrow\infty} \left[ \sup_{t\in \mathbb{R}^+} \mathbb{E}\left[ M_t^2 \mathbb{I}_{\left\{M_t^2> K\right\}}\right]\right] =0
\end{equation*}
I think it is...and my attempt at proving it so far is as follows:

[image: My attempt so far]

However I am getting stuck at the last step where I need to interchange the limit and the supremum...(I have highlighted this step in red). I know that we can interchange the limit and the suprermum if $\sup_{t\in \mathbb{R}^+} \mathbb{E}\left[ M_t^2 \mathbb{I}_{\left\{M_t^2> K\right\}}\right]$ converges uniformly to 0 when we take the limit as $C\rightarrow\infty$, but I couldn't show this either....

Any help would be greatly appreciated, whether it be:
1) showing another way of proving it, 
2) showing a way of getting around/proving the last step
3) telling me this statement isn't true (and if it isn't is there a counter example).

Many thanks!

Comment: Any family of random variables which is bounded in $L^p$ for some $p>1$ is uniformly integrable. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862747/sup-n-int-f-n1-gammad-mu-infty-implies-f-n-is-uniformly-int/1862752#1862752

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. May I ask - what does it mean for something to be "bounded in $L^p$?

Comment: It just means that the set $\{X_i:i\in I\}$ is a bounded subset of $L^p$. That is, there is some $C$ such that $||X_i||_p\leq C$ for all $i\in I$.

Comment: Many thanks. Looking at the link now - will let you know how it goes!

Comment: I personally like Chapter 11 from [this set of notes](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/gordanz/notes/theory_of_probability_I.pdf) for studying uniform integrability. Proposition 11.7 specifically is a really handy tool for recognizing precisely when a collection of random variables is UI.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by carmichael561, [a family of random variable with is bounded in $\mathbb L^p$ is uniformly integrable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862747/sup-n-int-f-n1-gammad-mu-infty-implies-f-n-is-uniformly-int/1862752#1862752). Note that the post addresses the case of sequences, but the same proof works for a family of random variables with an arbitrary index. This would be sufficient to prove uniform integrability of $\{\left\lvert M_t\right\rvert,t\geqslant 0\}$ but not that of $\{  M_t^2,t\geqslant 0\}$.

Here are the ideas to handle it.

1. It suffices to prove the uniform integrability of $\{M_n^2,n\in\mathbb N\}$.

   Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $t\in [n-1,n)$. Then for all positive $x$, 
   \begin{align}
   \Pr\left(\left\lvert M_t\right\rvert>x\right)&=\Pr\left(\left\lvert 
   \mathbb E\left[
   M_n\mid\mathcal F_t\right]\right\rvert>x\right)\\
   &\leqslant \frac 1x\mathbb E\left[\left\lvert 
   \mathbb E\left[
   M_n\mid\mathcal F_t\right]\right\rvert\mathbf 1\left\{\left\lvert 
   \mathbb E\left[
   M_n\mid\mathcal F_t\right]\right\rvert>x\right\}   \right]\\
   &\leqslant \frac 1x\mathbb E\left[
   \mathbb E\left[\left\lvert 
   M_n\right\rvert\mid\mathcal F_t\right]\mathbf 1\left\{\left\lvert 
   \mathbb E\left[
   M_n\mid\mathcal F_t\right]\right\rvert>x\right\}   \right].
   \end{align}
   Since the set $\left\{\left\lvert 
   \mathbb E\left[
   M_n\mid\mathcal F_t\right]\right\rvert>x\right\}$ belongs to $\mathcal F_t$, we obtain by definition of the conditional expectation that 
   $$\Pr\left(\left\lvert M_t\right\rvert>x\right)\leqslant \frac 1x\mathbb E\left[
    \left\lvert 
   M_n \right\rvert\mathbf 1\left\{\left\lvert 
   \mathbb E\left[
   M_n\mid\mathcal F_t\right]\right\rvert>x\right\}   \right].$$
   Observing that for all non-negative integrable random variable $X$ and any event $A$, 
   $$
   \mathbb E\left[X\mathbf 1_A\right]=\int_0^{+\infty}\Pr\left(\{X>t\}\cap A\right)dt
   \leqslant \frac x2\Pr(A)+\int_{x/2}^{+\infty}\Pr\left( X>t\right)dt\leqslant 
    \frac x2\Pr(A)+\frac 2x\mathbb E\left[\mathbf 1\{X>x/2\}\right],
   $$
   we get 
   $$\Pr\left(\left\lvert M_t\right\rvert>x\right)\leqslant \frac 4x\mathbb E\left[
    \left\lvert 
   M_n \right\rvert\mathbf 1\left\{\left\lvert 
   M_n\ \right\rvert>x/2\right\}   \right].$$
   To conclude, express $\mathbb E\left[M_t^2\mathbf 1\left\{\left\lvert 
   M_t  \right\rvert>R\right\}\right]$ in term of the tail of $\left\lvert 
   M_t  \right\rvert$.

   2. In order to show the uniform integrability of $\{M_n^2,n\in\mathbb N\}$, we apply Doob's inequality in order to see that $\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}M_n^2$ is integrable.

The concerns about the approach proposed in the opening post are the following:

- In the image, after the sentence "we may conclude that", the first equality is obvious ($C$ and $K$ play the same role).
- The red equality needs justifications, since it is in general false that we can exchange a limit and a supremum.